# What is the OpenID Connect access token for?

Tags: http, security, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

The OpenID Connect JWT token contains both an `id_token` and an `access_token` (Like `"access_token": "SlAV32hkKG"`).  What is the `access_token` for?

#### ANSWER EXAMPLE

Just adding an example to complement the answers taken from [this linked article](https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect#claims)

User Info Endpoint Request

```
GET /userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: openid.c2id.com
Authorization: Bearer SlAV32hkKG
```

User Info Endpoint Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "sub"                     : "alice",
  "email"                   : "alice@wonderland.net",
  "email_verified"          : true,
  "name"                    : "Alice Adams",
  "picture"                 : "https://c2id.com/users/alice.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the section 5.3 and 16.4 of the [specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html). The access token is used to access the userinfo endpoint which is a protected resource.

> 16.4.  Access Token Disclosure
>
> Access Tokens are credentials used to access Protected Resources, as defined in Section 1.4 of OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749]. Access Tokens represent an End-User's authorization and MUST NOT be exposed to unauthorized parties.

[...]

> 5.3.  UserInfo Endpoint
>
> The UserInfo Endpoint is an OAuth 2.0 Protected Resource that returns Claims about the authenticated End-User. To obtain the requested Claims about the End-User, the Client makes a request to the UserInfo Endpoint **using an Access Token obtained through OpenID Connect Authentication**. These Claims are normally represented by a JSON object that contains a collection of name and value pairs for the Claims.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** - ***Access token*** grants authorization to access a protected resource where the ***ID token*** is consumed by the client for authentication.

**Access token**

Being an extention to OAuth2.0, OpenID Connect keep tokens/prameters defined in OAuth2.0 specification. ***Access token*** is one such thing. As defined by the protocol, access token is used to access protected resources. It replaces user credentials, manually generated tokens or security keys which were used in good old days (ex:- Think about basic authentication).

Note the access token could be an opaque string. Which means it's nothing that could be consumed by the client which recieves it. But the authorization server knows what it is. For example, introspection endpoint ([RFC7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662)) can be used to validate the validity of an access token. And access token can be a JWT too depending on the usage and implementation.

**ID token**

This is what OpenID Connect introduced to OAuth2.0. ID token is a JWT and it is consumed by client to authenticate the end user(the resource owner). By validating an ID token, client have the ability to authenticate. Due to this fact, one can argue it surves one time usage.

Also note that in some implementations, ID tokens are being used as bearer tokens. That mean, ID token used like an access token for authentication and authorization.